# Google Sheets: Is it possible to simplify this formula? Preferably, I'd like it to calculate all the cells in the row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can the following formula be simplified as described in the paragraph below it?

`=(ABS(D$3-D5)+ABS(E$3-E5)+ABS(F$3-F5)+ABS(G$3-G5)+ABS(H$3-H5)+ABS(I$3-I5)+ABS(J$3-J5)+ABS(K$3-K5))/-1`

The problem is that I don't know how many columns I'm going to end up with, and I certainly don't want to continue manually writing each column into the formula. Is there I way to simplify this formula so that every column in a row is calculated?

I've been trying various formulas to no avail, and I can't get usable results via Google searches. I suppose I don't know how to effectively word the question without writing a paragraph.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

`=-SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(ABS(D$3:$3 - D5:5)))`

[image]

Comment: I appreciate it! I figured it out, and my answer is quite similar to yours. I didn't see your comment until I posted my solution and the page refreshed. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(ABS(D$3:$3-D5:5))/-1)`

Comment: try: `=INDEX(SUM(ABS(D$3:$3-D5:5))/-1)`